# can't install anyy programme LibreOffice Problem

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice

```
ff@ff:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge getdeb-repository
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet getdeb-repository
ssadmin991@SS1EPHARMA:~$ sudo apt-get remove install-info
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Vous pouvez lancer « apt-get -f install » pour corriger ces problèmes :
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 info : Dépend: install-info
 libreoffice-common : Recommande: xfonts-mathml mais ne sera pas installé
                      Casse: libreoffice-core (>= 1:3.6~) mais 1:4.3.4-0ubuntu1~precise1 devra être installé
                      Casse: libreoffice-style-galaxy (>= 1:3.6~) mais 1:4.3.4-0ubuntu1~precise1 devra être installé
 libreoffice-core : Dépend: libreoffice-common (> 1:4.3.4) mais 1:3.5.7-0ubuntu7 devra être installé
                    Casse: libreoffice-common (< 1:3.6.1~rc1) mais 1:3.5.7-0ubuntu7 devra être installé
E: Dépendances non satisfaites. Essayez « apt-get -f install » sans paquet
(ou indiquez une solution).




 Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 libreoffice-style-galaxy
   libreoffice-common
 libreoffice-core
   python-uno
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Tape tout en Français *et* en Anglais (fait traduire par Google Translate si ton Anglais est trop faible: je rédigerai ta question)

Answer (score 0):

To remove getdeb-repository test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

And run:

```
sudo -i 
add-apt-repository –remove getdeb-repository
```

or

```
sudo -i
mv $(grep -i –files-with-matches getdeb -R /etc/apt/sources.list*) ~/_backups/old-apt-repos/
```

To correct problems apt-get, run:

```
sudo -i
apt-get -f install
```